# How to avoid Index Fragmentation in datawarehosue database?

Tags: sql, database, indexing, data-warehouse, database-performance

I am new to a BI project with big-data processing overnights 6 out of 7 days on a week. I have noticed that processing time (in hours) increases as well as the year goes and I am commited to identify and try to fix it as much as possible.

One of the things I've identified is a high level of index fragmentation. On my research I found a way to get a report of:

1. avg fragmentation from 5% to 30%     --> this can be fixed with REORGANIZE Index
2. avg fragmentation from 30% or higher --> this can be fixed with REBUILD Index

Here's the reporte code:

```
SELECT 'ALTER INDEX [' + ix.name + '] ON [' + s.name + '].[' + t.name + '] ' +
       CASE 
            WHEN ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 30 THEN 'REBUILD' 
            ELSE 'REORGANIZE' 
        END +
       CASE 
            WHEN pc.partition_count > 1 THEN ' PARTITION = ' + cast(ps.partition_number as nvarchar(max)) 
            ELSE '' 
        END
FROM   sys.indexes AS ix 
        INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON (t.object_id = ix.object_id)
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON (t.schema_id = s.schema_id)
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT object_id, 
                            index_id, 
                            avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
                            partition_number
                     FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
                    ) ps ON (t.object_id = ps.object_id AND ix.index_id = ps.index_id)
        INNER JOIN ( SELECT object_id,
                            index_id,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT partition_number) AS partition_count
                     FROM sys.partitions
                     GROUP BY object_id, index_id
                    ) pc ON ( t.object_id = pc.object_id AND ix.index_id = pc.index_id)
WHERE  ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 10 AND
       ix.name IS NOT NULL
```

Early this week I run the report and got 32 fragmented indexes: 9 to REOGANIZE; 23 to REBUILD. I performed corrective action each day, get a fresh report and today I'm getting 26 fragmented indexes: 8 to REORGANIZE; 18 to REBUILD.

**Question**: the question is pretty obvious. I don't want to keep doing corrective maintenance but just be preventive and avoid the fragmentation produced during the nights. How can avoid the index fragmentation? Any suggest, advice, strategy?

General Info:

- Each FK has a non-clustered index over it.
- Interesting columns (no FK) being part of common joining conditions has non-clustered index associated.
- Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5294.00 (X64)

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

A number of things cause index defrags:

- Changing the value of indexed fields in a row
- Adding keys out of order
- Probably a whole load of other things for which dba.stackexchange.com is the best source

In my experience, the worst is the first: changing the value of indexed columns.

You should set up maintenance plans to run every night to reorg indexes. You can do this with SSMS:
[image: SSMS Maintenance Plan]

You can make it part of the backup. It should run after your overnight processing to repair the defragging that seems to be causing. This is something I have set up on all my production databases.

Comment: I'm trying to put this in practice. I created the maintenance plan, created a subplan with both Reorganize and Rebuild indexes over the tables I'm interested in and executed it. However, after success maintenance plan execution, I run the query posted before, and reported fragmented indexes are still there. Any clue what could be casuing that?

Comment: @G21 Indexes won't defragment sometimes if they are very small (in which case it won't matter) or if they are very large and there's not enough contiguous space for the index pages to be arranged in order.